# extend olink in odata4j library

Tags: java, odata4j

I want expert advice regarding my requirement – I hope you guys help me to solve this problem. I am using OData4j library

I am want to add uniqeId in my collection resource 
e.g.

Here uniqeId is not part of OData and Atom Pub specification but I want to implement this what is the best way ?
If I extend OLink then I have to extend other interface OLinks, OEntity etc.. I don’t want to increase extra overhead.

Is there any other way to add this uniqeId as a attribute in  tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [apache olingo library](https://olingo.apache.org/) to achieve this